# How Odoo to get values ids in each field

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I create functions

```
def create(self, values):
 #field name is 'promotions_type_line'
```

but i don't know how to get values from 'promotions_type_line' field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def create(self, values):
    result = super().create(values)
    line = result.promotions_type_line
    # Do your things here
    return result
```